# Inline command for matching the figure and tables numbering labels in a Dynamic Document R and Knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, inline-code, cross-reference

I´m working in a `rmardkown` / `knitr` for a `documentclass`:`book` and I´m chasing a way of getting `inline` command for figure/table auto-numbering following the chapter/session numbering reference as the same sequence I have for the figure/table caption numbering labels.

That is, the auto-numbering sequence labels  (with session hierarchy sequence such as 1.1, 1.2 1.3 for figures on chapter one and 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 for figures on chapter two and so on) before the figure/table caption (e.g: Figure 1.2: MyfigureName) are ok, but when I call an inline reference throughout the text in the dynamic document the output label thru the text for the figure/table is ignoring the session/chapters numbering and, instead, it is following an own different counting where the figures or the tables numbering is counting in an 'absolute' sequence counting along the document (e.g: Figure 1, 2,3,4....N for the N figures on the document).

What am I doing? I´m doing that by the `kfigr` R package by calling the inline command. Example below?

Text:

```
As you can see by the `r figr("MyChunkName",TRUE,type="Figure")` we have a plot.
```

The output here from that inline command will be something like:

".... by the  **Figure 10** we have..."

(assuming before we have 9 other figures on the document) inline with the text.

Where the related Chunk is something like:

````
```{r MyChunkName,anchor="Figure",results='asis',eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE,fig.caption="MyCarsPlot"}

plot(cars)

```
````

The output plot will be followed (below) by the captions with the numbering like:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (plot image)xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                           Figure 2.1: MyCarsPlot
```

(assuming the chunk is in section 2.1)

Where the "MyChunkName" is the link between inline command to the figure on that chunk.

Therefore **Figure 10** numbering output from inline command is not matching with **Figure 2.1** output from the chunk plot captions.

Another aspect is that I have figure/table resulting from chunk codes as well as by including thru `\includegraphics` called directly from the document (i.e, figures called outside the chunk). Therefore, the sequence numbering should count figure from chunks as well from latex `\begin{figure}`...`\end{figure}` command sequence.

After all,question:

- How to use inline cross-reference matching the same numbering figure/table labels in DDR and knitr?

or

- Does anybody have a .rmd source to share showing how such reference was done in your document?

Thanks

Fabio